# Shapely/Pyproj converts all polygon coordinates to inf

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, pyproj

After some libraries got updated, I can't convert a polygon between CRS in shapely/pyproj. Everything seems to be done according to [the documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.transform).

Pyproj version 2.4.2.post1, Shapely version 1.7.0

Here's the test code:

```
from shapely.ops import transform as transform_
from shapely.wkt import loads
import pyproj
from functools import partial
print(pyproj.__version__)
obj = loads('POLYGON ((101.6862738336452 3.1597141052896, 101.6862738336452 3.176801618144858, 101.6706701928565 3.176801618144858, 101.6706701928565 3.1597141052896, 101.6862738336452 3.1597141052896))')
crs_from = pyproj.CRS.from_string('epsg:4326')
print(repr(crs_from), crs_from.__class__)

crs_to = pyproj.CRS.from_string('epsg:3857')
print(repr(crs_to), crs_to.__class__)

print(obj.__class__)
print(obj.wkt)
print(transform_(partial(pyproj.transform, crs_from, crs_to), obj).wkt)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 /tmp/crs.py 
2.4.2.post1
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
 <class 'pyproj.crs.CRS'>
<Projected CRS: EPSG:3857>
Name: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- X[east]: Easting (metre)
- Y[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: World - 85°S to 85°N
- bounds: (-180.0, -85.06, 180.0, 85.06)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator
- method: Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
 <class 'pyproj.crs.CRS'>
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
POLYGON ((101.6862738336452 3.1597141052896, 101.6862738336452 3.176801618144858, 101.6706701928565 3.176801618144858, 101.6706701928565 3.1597141052896, 101.6862738336452 3.1597141052896))
POLYGON ((inf inf, inf inf, inf inf, inf inf, inf inf))
```

After changing the code to use `pyproj.Transformer...` still getting the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to a related pyproj issue: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/538

Here is a link to more information about the axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6

In summary, you need to either be aware of your axis order on input/output or use the `always_xy=True` when creating the `pyproj.Transformer`.

Comment: If the same answer applies to two questions it often indicates that the two questions should be first made into duplicates, and later merged.

Comment: Agreed - thanks! I wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: At 3,000 rep you get the close/re-open vote privilege.  In the meantime you can flag it for the review queue or a moderator to handle.